# Karma tests fail with Browser DISCONNECTED error, exit code: 1

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

We have a total of 2016 unit test cases written with Jasmine and are using Karma to run them. The tests run for a period of 1 min 30 sec to 2 min and then suddenly Karma disconnects from the browser.[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QGVc.png) is a screenshot of the console logs.

The problem is that I am not able to diagnose why that is happening and which test case is causing it to get disconnected. I have tried different reporters of Karma to be able to identify the test case which forces it to disconnect from the browser but have been unsuccessful so far.

I have also tried running the tests in short batches to be able to drill down to the error test case (in case it is a test case error and not Karma configuration) but so far, the error has been thrown for all batches.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119506/karma-jasmine-times-out-without-running-tests) post, I have tried setting the `browserNoActivityTimeout` to as high as 10 minutes (600000ms) but still no resolution. Also, the post mentions that there might be a problem with insufficient memory, so I have tried running the cases in one 8GB RAM and one 16GB RAM systems (Windows 10 on both).

Here's the complete stack trace:

```
[02:06:48] Error: MyApp Chromebook Unit tests failed with exitCode: 1
at formatError (C:\Users\barnadeep.bhowmik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:169:10)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\barnadeep.bhowmik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:195:15)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Gulp.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (C:\Users\barnadeep.bhowmik\Desktop\Projects\MyProject\test-player-15-may\myapp-chrome\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
at C:\Users\barnadeep.bhowmik\Desktop\Projects\MyProject\test-player-15-may\myapp-chrome\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
at finish (C:\Users\barnadeep.bhowmik\Desktop\Projects\MyProject\test-player-15-may\myapp-chrome\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
at cb (C:\Users\barnadeep.bhowmik\Desktop\Projects\MyProject\test-player-15-may\myapp-chrome\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
at C:\Users\barnadeep.bhowmik\Desktop\Projects\MyProject\test-player-15-may\myapp-chrome\build\tasks\test.js:18:13
at removeAllListeners (C:\Users\barnadeep.bhowmik\Desktop\Projects\MyProject\test-player-15-may\myapp-chrome\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:336:7)
at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\barnadeep.bhowmik\Desktop\Projects\MyProject\test-player-15-may\myapp-chrome\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:347:9)
at Server.g (events.js:291:16)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at Server.emit (events.js:185:7)
at emitCloseNT (net.js:1555:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:71:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Here's my config file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      'other_dependencies/**.*.js',
      'src/app/app.js',
      'src/app/pack1-components/**/*.js',
      'src/app/pack2-components/**/*.js',
      'src/**/*.html'
    ],
    exclude: [
      'src/some-folder/*',
    ],
    port: 8081,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['ChromeNoSandbox'],//temp fix for Chrome Browser 'Chrome'
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeNoSandbox: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    reporters: ["spec","progress","coverage","html"],
    specReporter: {
        maxLogLines: 5,             // limit number of lines logged per test
        suppressErrorSummary: false, // do not print error summary
        suppressFailed: false,      // do not print information about failed tests
        suppressPassed: false,      // do not print information about passed tests
        suppressSkipped: true,      // do not print information about skipped tests
        showSpecTiming: false,      // print the time elapsed for each spec
        failFast: true              // test would finish with error when a first fail occurs. 
      },
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js':['coverage'],
      'src/**/*.html':['ng-html2js']
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      type: 'lcov',
      dir: 'qualityreports/testresults/unit/coverage/'
    },
    htmlReporter: {
      outputFile: 'qualityreports/testresults/unit/testresults.html'
    },
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 600000,
    captureTimeout: 60000, 
    browserDisconnectTimeout : 60000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance : 1,
      ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
    },
    plugins: [
      'karma-jasmine','karma-chrome-launcher','karma-coverage','karma-htmlfile-reporter','karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',"karma-spec-reporter"],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39468565/karma-disconnects-before-all-tests-run) is a similar post but it did not have all details, hence posting mine. Any help would be deeply appreciated.